# How can I support an unknown or other value for a Serde enum?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a JSON API that returns an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "PrivatePort": 2222,
  "PublicPort": 3333,
  "Type": "tcp"
}
```

To capture this, I have an enum and a struct:

```rust
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum PortType {
    Sctp,
    Tcp,
    Udp,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
pub struct PortMapping {
    pub private_port: u16,
    pub public_port: u16,
    #[serde(rename = "Type")]
    pub port_type: PortType,
}
```

Right now, this API only supports the three protocols listed in `PortType`, but let's assume that support for `DCCP` is added in the future. I do not want clients of the API to start failing simply because of an unknown string in a configuration option they might not be looking at.

To address this, I've added an `Unknown` variant with a `String` to represent the value:

```rust
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum PortType {
    Sctp,
    Tcp,
    Udp,
    Unknown(String),
}
```

The goal here is to end up with the slightly-inconvenient `PortType::Unknown("dccp")` value when an unknown value is passed in. Of course, this does not do what I would like out-of-box -- passing the unknown `"dccp"` value will result in:

```
Error("unknown variant `dccp`, expected one of `sctp`, `tcp`, `udp`, `unknown`", line: 1, column: 55)
```

Is there a Serde configuration for doing what I want or should I resort to manually writing `Deserialize` and `Serialize` implementations for `PortType`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now use the `#[serde(untagged)]` attribute on the variant level, to capture unknown variants.

```rust
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum PortType {
    Sctp,
    Tcp,
    Udp,
    #[serde(untagged)]
    Unknown(String),
}
```

Not to be confused with the [untagged](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) attribute on the enum level.

I can't find any documentations for this attribute though.

Thanks https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/912#issuecomment-1868785603

Answer (score 12):

Try use [serde-enum-str](https://docs.rs/serde-enum-str)

```
#[derive(serde_enum_str::Deserialize_enum_str, serde_enum_str::Serialize_enum_str)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum PortType {
    Sctp,
    Tcp,
    Udp,
    #[serde(other)]
    Unknown(String),
}
```

Comment: This requires some more visibility! It solves the issue of "extensible" string enum in both directions - and also allows code programmatically to use "to_string()" and "parse()" to go between string and enum (rather than forcing the use of serde for this serialization).

Answer (score 7):

There's an issue for this, though it's been open for 3 years with no full resolution so far. [Serde #912](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/912).

What seems to be currently implemented (though undocumented) at the time of this post is `#[serde(other)]`. It can only be applied to unit enum fields, which limits its usefulness:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, PartialEq)]
#[serde(tag = "tag")]
enum Target {
   A(()),
   B(()),
   #[serde(other)]
   Others
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Target::Others, from_str::<Target>(r#"{ "tag": "blablah" }"#).unwrap());
}
```

Other than that, the only other method as of this writing is writing your own `Deserialize` implementation.

Answer (score 6):

I do it with serde(from="String")

```rust
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case", from="String")]
pub enum PortType {
    Sctp,
    Tcp,
    Udp,
    Unknown(String),
}

impl From<String> for PortType {
    fn from(s: String)->Self {
        use PortType::*;

        return match s.as_str() {
            "sctp" => Sctp,
            "tcp" => Tcp,
            "udp" => Udp,
            _ => Unknown(s)
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
pub struct PortMapping {
    pub private_port: u16,
    pub public_port: u16,
    #[serde(rename = "Type")]
    pub port_type: PortType,
}
```

Comment: This is a neat trick, but note that it only works for "simple" enum types, i.e. those that don't have additional values.

Answer (score 3):

Simple case should be fine with this:

```rust
use serde::de::Visitor;
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize};
use serde_json::from_str;

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
pub struct PortMapping {
    pub private_port: u16,
    pub public_port: u16,
    #[serde(rename = "Type")]
    pub port_type: PortType,
}

#[derive(Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Serialize, Debug)]
pub enum PortType {
    Sctp,
    Tcp,
    Udp,
    Unknown(String),
}

const PORT_TYPE: &'static [(&'static str, PortType)] = &[
    ("sctp", PortType::Sctp),
    ("tcp", PortType::Tcp),
    ("udp", PortType::Udp),
];

impl From<String> for PortType {
    fn from(variant: String) -> Self {
        PORT_TYPE
            .iter()
            .find(|(id, _)| *id == &*variant)
            .map(|(_, port_type)| port_type.clone())
            .unwrap_or(PortType::Unknown(variant))
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for PortType {
    fn from(variant: &'a str) -> Self {
        PORT_TYPE
            .iter()
            .find(|(id, _)| *id == &*variant)
            .map(|(_, port_type)| port_type.clone())
            .unwrap_or_else(|| PortType::Unknown(variant.to_string()))
    }
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for PortType {
    fn deserialize<D>(de: D) -> Result<PortType, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct PortTypeVisitor {}

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for PortTypeVisitor {
            type Value = PortType;

            fn expecting(
                &self,
                fmt: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>,
            ) -> std::result::Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
                fmt.write_str("We expected a string")
            }

            fn visit_str<E>(self, variant: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E> {
                Ok(variant.into())
            }

            fn visit_string<E>(self, variant: String) -> Result<Self::Value, E> {
                Ok(variant.into())
            }
        }

        de.deserialize_string(PortTypeVisitor {})
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = r#"
    {
      "PrivatePort": 2222,
      "PublicPort": 3333,
      "Type": "dccp"
    }
    "#;

    let result: Result<PortMapping, _> = from_str(input);

    println!("{:#?}", result);
}
```

I don't think there is a idiomatic way to do this, that could be included in the future.

Comment: Yes there is an idiomatic way to do this that could be included in the future: `#[serde(other)`. See https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/912